# OpenCV plays back video way faster than the original recording

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import time

# Open the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('marker test.mp4')

# Get the frames per second (fps) of the video
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Read the first frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

while ret:
    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Video Playback', frame)
    
    # Wait for the specified delay to maintain the original timeline
    delay = int(1000 / fps)  # Calculate the delay in milliseconds
    if cv2.waitKey(delay) == 27:  # Exit if the 'Esc' key is pressed
        break
    
    # Read the next frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

# Release the video capture object and close the windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have here a simple block of dumbed down code that reads a .mp4 video recording and has it replay out by cv2. The video was recorded at 30 fps by a webcam. I am aware that cv2 plays out videos at a rate different from the fps of the video, so I tried to correct it by inserting a `delay` variable to account for this discrepancy. However, it doesn't fix the issue.

The original video is about 13 seconds long. With this code, the replay of the video was dragged out to as far as 20 seconds long. Without the fps fix, and assuming `delay = 1` as typically is the default, the video replay only lasted about 6+ seconds long, which sounds about right as I'm running this on a PC that is at 60hz refresh rate.

What am I getting wrong here? How do I get cv2 to play out the video in the exact time frame as with the original video?

Comment: "What am I getting wrong here?" -- you expect that the rest of the loop body executes instantaneously, and that `waitKey` waits for exactly the time specified. That bit about 60 Hz being "about right" is probably off too, more likely a coincidence.

Comment: Right. How do I address this issue, though? I manually tried playing around by hard coding delay with various numbers and it seemed like when delay = 10, the video runtime between cv2 replay and the actual video is just about on par. But I couldn't make sense how to derive to delay=10.

Comment: opencv is for computer vision, not for video playback. video playback involves "high precision" multimedia timers. the "cheap" timers in an operating system run on scheduler time slices. those can be 1/64 of a second on windows. that'd give you jitter. -- besides, waitKey contains sleep. sleep is not a timer. it's not exact. it sleeps at least as much as requested. your process may not get scheduled the instant the sleep is over. and all the other code in your loop costs time too. you need to calculate the sleep time according to a clock, for every frame.